# why can't I `rails server stop`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is there a rails server restart command given, but not a rails server stop?

```
$ bundle exec rails restart
$ bundle exec rails stop
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'stop' (see --tasks)
```

Comment: what the server type is? webrick, puma, unicorn?

Comment: the default that came with rails 5 (puma).

Comment: heh as you probably knows already to stop puma server there is cmd CTRL+c on keyboard and there are also some option to kip pid if server was started as daemon with -d, now why puma does not have rails stop command I think you can ask and request this feature on puma github  https://github.com/puma/puma

Comment: two issues: 1) can't do ctrl-c on a backgrounded process. 2) puma is used not just by rails. so asking for a rails command/feature at the puma repo might not be a good idea

Comment: process as a daemon you know about lsof -wni tcp:port you running site and using process id to kil like  kill -9 processid .I dont see any problem,  even in another use of puma as server for asking for a new syntax command  for stopping a process. Probably  there are already some options/solutions but I also couldn't find it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep command to check for any Rails process:

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

And then to kill the specific process:

`kill -9 {process_id}`

If you need to kill all Rails processes, you can try:

```
killall -9 rails
```